# Declaring Doxygen comments for specialized classes

Tags: c++, templates, doxygen

I have the following class template:

```
template<int N>
class A {
    virtual std::array<double, N> a(std::array<double, N> x) = 0
    virtual ~A() { }
}
```

and the following template specialization:

```
class B : public A<3> {
    std::array<double, 3> a(std::array<double, 3> x) {
        return std::array<double, 3>(); // Returns (0,0,0) for now
    }
}
```

and I want to document this code using Doxygen. I've added some documentation for the template, which shows up fine when viewing the documentation for `A`:

```
/**
 * @brief Calculate a vector quantity of length `N` based on another
 *
 * @param x The input vector
 * @return A `std::array<double, N>` with the calculated vector quantity
 */
 virtual std::array<double, N> a(std::array<double, N> x) = 0;
```

It also shows up when I view the documentation for `B`, if I expand the section "Public member functions inherited from `A`".

However, I can't get it to propagate to the documentation of `B::a` - when I scroll down the page, the function is listed with a new signature (specifying `std::array<double, 3>` rather than `N`) and with all the other stuff unknown. This is irregardless if I add some documentation to the method in `B`.

For non-template classes, I had no problem letting the documentation "propagate" so that docs of the parameters etc in the interface were shown also for the concrete implementations. Is there a way to achieve the same thing for templates and their specializations? How?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question yet? I'm having the same problem...

Comment: @DeManu: No, unfortunately I haven't looked at the code for this project in a long time. I went back to the code repo now and looked for where I had attempted this, but I couldn't find it - it might never have been checked in. So I'm afraid I can't help you further :(